# Get key name from a JSON object using json_decode

Tags: php, json

I've following JSON string

```
{
   "daily":{
      "1518220800000":174,
      "1518307200000":175,
      "1518393600000":179,
      "1518480000000":181
   },
   "average":{
      "1518220800000":171,
      "1518307200000":171,
      "1518393600000":171,
      "1518480000000":172
   }
}
```

and I want to access first key name `1518220800000` in  `daily` object using PHP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more helpful advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
$jsonstr = '{
   "daily":{
      "1518220800000":174,
      "1518307200000":175,
      "1518393600000":179,
      "1518480000000":181
   },
   "average":{
      "1518220800000":171,
      "1518307200000":171,
      "1518393600000":171,
      "1518480000000":172
   }
}';
$json = json_decode($jsonstr, true);
echo array_keys($json['daily'])[0];
```

Output:

```
1518220800000
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-json-data-with-php-or-javascript/), how to get data from a nested array:

```
$data = '{
   "daily":{
      "1518220800000":174,
      "1518307200000":175,
      "1518393600000":179,
      "1518480000000":181
   },
   "average":{
      "1518220800000":171,
      "1518307200000":171,
      "1518393600000":171,
      "1518480000000":172
   }
}';

$character = json_decode($data,true);
echo $character[daily][1518220800000];
```

Output: 174

Comment: No I needed key name not value.. @Nic 's answer is right thanks

Comment: @NadeemGorsi Ooops, Sorry, I didn't see that. Anyway glad to solve your problem